# Random WiFi disconnects on TP-LINK TL-WN821N

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 14.10, disconnect

I have random WiFi disconnects on my Kodibuntu box (upgraded to Ubuntu Vivid right now). Sometimes connection lasts for several days, sometimes - for several minutes.

The thing that helped this time is `sudo service network-manager restart`.
Sometimes replugging adapter helps. Anyways it happens on all available versions of Ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.04.

During last disconnection I've launched wireless-info script, here is result:
http://pastebin.com/Ue610Tht

Will appreciate any idea.

Comment: See if `sudo iw reg set RU` helps any as your computer thinks you are in China

Comment: It's even more strange, but internet stooped working again. [Here](http://pastebin.com/QmshRZWe) is new wireless-info. Thing is status says it's connected…

Answer (score 0):

I see a few wireless access points that are on the same channel, so I would change the wifi router to channel 9 and see if wifi improves.  You could also go into Network Manager settings for your connection and disable IPv6